# ValueError: RSA key format is not supported

Tags: python, шифрование, rsa

Делаю школьный проект (мессенджер с шифрованием) и возникла проблема. При получении публичного ключа с сервера вылезает ошибка RSA key format is not supported. Если считывать ключ с файла все работает. Код сервера и модуля шифрования прилагаю.

Шифрование:

```
import requests
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from Cryptodome.Random import get_random_bytes
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP

code = 'nice'
receiver = 'alice'

def crypto():
    # Генерация ключа RSA
    RSA_key = RSA.generate(2048)

    # Генерация приватного ключа
    pr_key = RSA_key.exportKey(
        passphrase=code,
        pkcs=8,
        protection="scryptAndAES128-CBC"
    )

    with open('key.bin', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pr_key)

    # Генерация публичного ключа с помощью приватного
    pu_key = RSA_key.public_key().exportKey()

    response = requests.post(
        'http://127.0.0.1:5000/change_key',
        json={'login': receiver, 'key': str(pu_key)}
    )


def encrypt(item):
    response = ''
    try:
        response = requests.get(
            'http://127.0.0.1:5000/send_key',
            params={'receiver': receiver}
        )
    except:
        pass

    recipient_key = RSA.import_key(response.json()['key'], passphrase=code)
    session_key = get_random_bytes(16)
    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)

    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
    ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(item)

    return [cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key), cipher_aes.nonce, tag, ciphertext]


def decrypt(enc_data):
    private_key = RSA.import_key(
        open('key.bin').read(),
        passphrase=code
    )

    enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = [
        enc_data[x] for x in range(0, 4)
    ]

    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)

    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
    data = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)

    return data


crypto()
item = input().encode('UTF-8')
print(decrypt(encrypt(item)).decode('UTF-8'))
```

Сервер:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import json
import time

# БД пользователя в json вместо csv
file = 'users.json'
data = json.load(open(file))
app = Flask(__name__)
messages = []


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World <a href="/status">Status</a>'


@app.route("/status")
def status_view():
    return {
        'status': True,
        'name': 'NICE',
        'time': datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d - %H:%M'),
        'time_for_sort': time.time()
    }


# Отправка публичного ключа по запросу
@app.route("/send_key", methods=['GET'])
def send_key():
    login = request.args['receiver']
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i]["login"] == login:
            return {'key': data[i]['key']}


@app.route("/change_key", methods=['POST'])
def change_key():
    login = request.json['login']
    key = request.json['key']

    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i]["login"] == login:
            data[i]["key"] = key

    return {'ok': True}
```

Comment: Ну вы же ключ в строку превращаете перед пересылкой `'key': str(pu_key)`. А обратное превращение в `bytes` где? Гоняйте байты через `key_as_text = pu_key.hex()` `pu_key = bytes.fromhex(key_as_text)` - так проще. Или конвертацию в строку перед посылкой делайте через `'key': pu_key.decode()` (раз уж ключ и так текстовый по сути).

Comment: Сработало, большое вам спасибо